# How to make padding count as part of an <a> tag (html/css)

Tags: html, css

When I click on the text the new link opens as expected, however is there a way so that when I click on the padding which is also set to a greyish background color and orange rollover which will also open the link?

http://postimg.org/image/4olp43nar/fb37a8ac/

[image]

**javascript is below**

```
sophiaList += "<li class='sophia_list_itemb' ><a class='sophia_book_link' 
href='" + neighborUrl + params + "' onclick='window.open(this.href); return false;' >" + image_title
        + "</a></li>";
```

**css**

```
.sophia-books-listView li {
display: block !important;
/*height: 175px !important;*/
position: relative !important;
margin-bottom: 35px !important;
text-align:left !important;
font-family: verdana !important;
font-style: bold;
font-size: 13px;
background-color: #EBEBEB !important;
padding: 8px !important;
-moz-border-radius: 15px;
border-radius: 15px;
box-shadow: -4px 3px 4px rgba(0, 0, 12, 0.72);
margin-left: 2px;
padding-left: 5px;
width: 80%;}
```

refer to the image linked. thanks.

Comment: Downvoters please let the 6-rep OP know WHY you downvote?

Answer (score 2):

You can make padding count as part of the total width and height of an element using the `border-box` [**box-sizing**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/box-sizing) property, like this:

```
.element {
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

Some people propose using [**box-sizing on a *universal* level**](http://paulirish.com/2012/box-sizing-border-box-ftw/), and I've had pretty good results doing that:

```
*, *:before, *:after {
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, however this has not solved the issue. Thanks for the advice on box sizing

Answer (score 0):

Link tags aka. ancor tags is INLINE tags. which have the same length as the text inside it.

So you need to convert your link to a BLOCK element.

```
display: block;
width: xxxxpx;
height: xxxxpx;
```

You can modify the CSS above as you like.

Comment: Its already been defined as a block element. The first css rule :)

Answer (score 0):

This is actually the default. The padding IS considered part of the anchor tag and is therefore click-able.

**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/danield770/KqHC2/1/)**

```
<a href="#">Clicking on the padded area also works</a>

a
{
    padding: 20px;
    background: orange;
}
```

Comment: Really strange It is not working for my element, maybe having the li in an a tag alters it somewhat